# Different Data Format in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have been given an assignment where I have to make some modifications in the current project. The assignment reads as :

> Write an example which uses the data-format attribute to request data on another form (ex: string of binary data for an image).
>   For your information, right now on the html file:
>
> ```
> data-format="canvas" uses will return data adapted to canvas if it is available
> data-format="binary" uses will return binary  data if available
> data-format="canvas,binary" uses will return data adapted to canvas if it is available, or binary data otherwise.
> ```

I did not understand the binary part. Why would anyone want string of binary data for an image? To add flexibility?

Comment: Whether there is a reason or not, it's an example. I don't think the actual values and the response matter (in this part), your task is to process them properly.

Comment: I can think of many ways to process canvas images. But, binary? Consider there is an image in binary (as @Quentin mentioned), so the user will get string of binary when he goes to that particular page?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are supposed to do with the data, you know the whole project. If you are wondering about whether 'binary' makes sense in this context and what it exactly means, ask the person who give you the assignment. How are we supposed to know?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should have been more clear when I asked the question. But I just wanted to know if overall binary format (not in this project's context) makes any sense? Like SVG provides high quality image, can be searched, indexed, and scripted, is there any advantage of using binary form? that was the main query.

Answer (score 0):

"binary" in this context means "not text". Most image formats are not text based (SVG being the notable exception).